# How do I parse this php array file into Access?

Tags: php, mysql, ms-access

This is output from a mysql export function.  Problem is I don't know the best way to put this into Access.  From there I can write PHP to parse it.

```
<?php
/**
 * Export to PHP Array plugin for PHPMyAdmin
 * @author Geoffray Warnants
 * @version 0.2b
 */

//
// Database "nhbdir_newdb3"
//

// nhbdir_newdb3.jos_banner
$jos_banner = array(
  array('bid'=>1,'cid'=>1,'type'=>'banner','name'=>'OSM 1','alias'=>'osm-1','imptotal'=>0,'impmade'=>44,'clicks'=>0,'imageurl'=>'osmbanner1.png','clickurl'=>'http://www.opensourcematters.org','date'=>'2004-07-07 15:31:29','showBanner'=>1,'checked_out'=>0,'checked_out_time'=>'0000-00-00 00:00:00','editor'=>'','custombannercode'=>'','catid'=>13,'description'=>'','sticky'=>0,'ordering'=>1,'publish_up'=>'0000-00-00 00:00:00','publish_down'=>'0000-00-00 00:00:00','tags'=>'','params'=>''),
  array('bid'=>2,'cid'=>1,'type'=>'banner','name'=>'OSM 2','alias'=>'osm-2','imptotal'=>0,'impmade'=>50,'clicks'=>0,'imageurl'=>'osmbanner2.png','clickurl'=>'http://www.opensourcematters.org','date'=>'2004-07-07 15:31:29','showBanner'=>1,'checked_out'=>0,'checked_out_time'=>'0000-00-00 00:00:00','editor'=>'','custombannercode'=>'','catid'=>13,'description'=>'','sticky'=>0,'ordering'=>2,'publish_up'=>'0000-00-00 00:00:00','publish_down'=>'0000-00-00 00:00:00','tags'=>'','params'=>''),
  array('bid'=>3,'cid'=>1,'type'=>'','name'=>'Joomla!','alias'=>'joomla','imptotal'=>0,'impmade'=>279,'clicks'=>0,'imageurl'=>'','clickurl'=>'http://www.joomla.org','date'=>'2006-05-29 14:21:28','showBanner'=>1,'checked_out'=>0,'checked_out_time'=>'0000-00-00 00:00:00','editor'=>'','custombannercode'=>'<a href=\"{CLICKURL}\" target=\"_blank\">{NAME}</a>
<br/>
Joomla! The most popular and widely used Open Source CMS Project in the world.','catid'=>14,'description'=>'','sticky'=>0,'ordering'=>1,'publish_up'=>'0000-00-00 00:00:00','publish_down'=>'0000-00-00 00:00:00','tags'=>'','params'=>''),
  array('bid'=>4,'cid'=>1,'type'=>'','name'=>'JoomlaCode','alias'=>'joomlacode','imptotal'=>0,'impmade'=>279,'clicks'=>0,'imageurl'=>'','clickurl'=>'http://joomlacode.org','date'=>'2006-05-29 14:19:26','showBanner'=>1,'checked_out'=>0,'checked_out_time'=>'0000-00-00 00:00:00','editor'=>'','custombannercode'=>'<a href=\"{CLICKURL}\" target=\"_blank\">{NAME}</a>
<br/>
JoomlaCode, development and distribution made easy.','catid'=>14,'description'=>'','sticky'=>0,'ordering'=>2,'publish_up'=>'0000-00-00 00:00:00','publish_down'=>'0000-00-00 00:00:00','tags'=>'','params'=>''),
  array('bid'=>5,'cid'=>1,'type'=>'','name'=>'Joomla! Extensions','alias'=>'joomla-extensions','imptotal'=>0,'impmade'=>274,'clicks'=>0,'imageurl'=>'','clickurl'=>'http://extensions.joomla.org','date'=>'2006-05-29 14:23:21','showBanner'=>1,'checked_out'=>0,'checked_out_time'=>'0000-00-00 00:00:00','editor'=>'','custombannercode'=>'<a href=\"{CLICKURL}\" target=\"_blank\">{NAME}</a>
<br/>
Joomla! Components, Modules, Plugins and Languages by the bucket load.','catid'=>14,'description'=>'','sticky'=>0,'ordering'=>3,'publish_up'=>'0000-00-00 00:00:00','publish_down'=>'0000-00-00 00:00:00','tags'=>'','params'=>''),
  array('bid'=>6,'cid'=>1,'type'=>'','name'=>'Joomla! Shop','alias'=>'joomla-shop','imptotal'=>0,'impmade'=>274,'clicks'=>0,'imageurl'=>'','clickurl'=>'http://shop.joomla.org','date'=>'2006-05-29 14:23:21','showBanner'=>1,'checked_out'=>0,'checked_out_time'=>'0000-00-00 00:00:00','editor'=>'','custombannercode'=>'<a href=\"{CLICKURL}\" target=\"_blank\">{NAME}</a>
<br/>
For all your Joomla! merchandise.','catid'=>14,'description'=>'','sticky'=>0,'ordering'=>4,'publish_up'=>'0000-00-00 00:00:00','publish_down'=>'0000-00-00 00:00:00','tags'=>'','params'=>''),
  array('bid'=>7,'cid'=>1,'type'=>'','name'=>'Joomla! Promo Shop','alias'=>'joomla-promo-shop','imptotal'=>0,'impmade'=>50,'clicks'=>1,'imageurl'=>'shop-ad.jpg','clickurl'=>'http://shop.joomla.org','date'=>'2007-09-19 17:26:24','showBanner'=>1,'checked_out'=>0,'checked_out_time'=>'0000-00-00 00:00:00','editor'=>'','custombannercode'=>'','catid'=>33,'description'=>'','sticky'=>0,'ordering'=>3,'publish_up'=>'0000-00-00 00:00:00','publish_down'=>'0000-00-00 00:00:00','tags'=>'','params'=>''),
  array('bid'=>8,'cid'=>1,'type'=>'','name'=>'Joomla! Promo Books','alias'=>'joomla-promo-books','imptotal'=>0,'impmade'=>57,'clicks'=>0,'imageurl'=>'shop-ad-books.jpg','clickurl'=>'http://shop.joomla.org/index.php?option=com_wrapper&Itemid=8','date'=>'2007-09-19 17:28:01','showBanner'=>1,'checked_out'=>0,'checked_out_time'=>'0000-00-00 00:00:00','editor'=>'','custombannercode'=>'','catid'=>33,'description'=>'','sticky'=>0,'ordering'=>4,'publish_up'=>'0000-00-00 00:00:00','publish_down'=>'0000-00-00 00:00:00','tags'=>'','params'=>'')
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit rough, but you can save a file as a [CSV file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) and then import it into Excel, copy it over to your clipboard and paste it into Access:

```
/**
 * save array as CSV file, first line will be keys as
 * field specifier
 *
 * @param array $data
 * @param string $filename
 */
function array_csv_save(array $data, $filename) {
    $handle = fopen($filename, 'w');
    $names = array_keys($data[0]);
    fputcsv($handle, $names);
    foreach($data as $fields) {
        fputcsv($handle, $fields);
    }
    fclose($handle);
}

$data = $jos_banner;
$columns = array_keys($data[0]);
array_unshift($data, $columns);
array_csv_save($data, $filename);
```

Specify `$filename` to save your data.

The other alternative is to open a ([odbc](http://php.net/manual/en/book.uodbc.php)?) based database connection to your Access database and insert your values. But I'm not fluent with that, so can't provide any useful code.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried just exporting from mysql to a .csv and then import that CSV into access? Save the .csv file and open it with access and it should prompt you with a wizard to import the data.

Comment: This here isn't an answer, more curiosity... Why are you exporting from MySQL to Access?  Will you be moving it back to the MySQL or leaving it in Access? The "From there I can write PHP to parse it" is the comment that struck my curiosity...